# Show that $g$ and $h$ are constant functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and $g(x)=\min\{f(t) \mid t\in[x-1,x]\}$ and $h(x)=\max \{f(t) \mid t\in[x-1,x]\}$ s.t. $g(x)+h(x)=0$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that $g$ and $h$ are constant functions.

I know that $f$ is bounded on $[x-1, x]$ and it cans reach her bounds but now I am stuck.

Comment: I think the idea might be that $f$ could be oscillating between a max and a min with a frequency (although not necessarily periodic) such that every interval of unit length contains at least one max and one min (which must be the negative of the max). I ***think*** that you may be able to show by continuity that any interval contains a finite number of these peaks & troughs. Then, in a proof by contradiction, if you assume that $g$ or $h$ is not constant, I think you may be able to show that you can position an interval so that it contains a higher peak than the negative of any trough.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564107/problem-involving-maximum-and-minimum-of-a-continuous-function